# How to translate "Case Sensitive"?

Tags: tradução-inglês, termos-em-inglês

How should I translate "case sensitive" to portuguese? I am translating a document and there is a strict need to avoid foreign terms.

---

Como devo traduzir o termo da língua inglesa "case sensitive" para o português? Estou traduzindo um documento e foi-me exigido evitar estrangeirismos.

**Por favor a lista abaixo serve apenas de exemplo. Caso tenha sugestão diferente vá em frente.** (para manter o texto conciso, vamos evitar o '(...) e minúsculas.';

Algumas idéias que tive:

- Sensível a maiúsculas
- Sensível a caixa [i.e. caixa alta/baixa lá das máquinas de datilografia]
- Diferenciar maiúsculas

Há [este artigo do ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-traducao-de-case-sensitive/27262) recomendando deixar sem tradução por se tratar de termo técnico restrito a um nicho, mas não se aplica no meu caso.

Qual a melhor tradução? O público-alvo é formado na área de computação e tecnologia de informação. A tradução segue o acordo ortográfico, mas se destina a todo o público lusofônico, seja de Portugal, Brasil, Angola, etc...

Dê motivos para justificar a escolha, por favor.

Comment: Como nós usamos sempre é *case-sensitive*, qualquer termo em português que uses, a menos que seja longo e muito descritivo, arrisca-se a não ser compreendido. Uma opção, para um termo conciso, é na primeira utilização explicares numa nota de tradutor, no texto ou numa nota de rodapé (e talvez num glossário em apêndice?). Agora, queres um termo bem conciso e (demasiado?) bem humorado?  Quem discrimina entre sexos é sexista; entre raças, racista. Então, *caixista*: discrimina entre caixa alta e caixa baixa.

Answer (score 2):

*"Sensível a maiúsculas"* soa bem, mas ainda sim acho que não seria de tom claro.

Quando for sensível (diferencia) acho que teria que ser completo:

- sensível a maiúsculas e minúsculas

E quando for insensível (não diferencia):

- não (é) sensível a maiúsculas e minúsculas

Ainda sim na maioria das vezes entre pessoas da área de TI ou que tem alguma noção usamos mesmo:

- case-sensitive

E quando o termo não é compreensível acabamos por dizer:

- diferencia minusculas de maiúsculas

Em um dialogo por exemplo:

> - João: Por que JavaScript não reconhece a minha função?
> - Raul: Verifique se é *case-sensitive*
> - João: Não entendi
> - Raul: JavaScript diferencia minusculas de maiúsculas, verifique se todas letras estão iguais

Não é um grande exemplo, mas costuma ser algo assim.

Recomendo que leia isto: [Como traduzir para o português alguns termos em inglês utilizados em programação de computadores?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/140/8)

Comment: Neste contexto, *case* significa 'caixa'. Vê  [Etymoline (n2)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=case) e [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Terminology). Upper-case = caixa alta; lower-case = caixa baixa. Nas tipografias, as letras minúsculas e outros carateres mais usados ficavam numa caixa mais abaixo (mais acessível ao utilizador); as maiúsculas, numa caixa mais acima. Vê também a [Wikipédia em português](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caixa_alta_e_caixa_baixa#Etimologia_de_caixa_alta).

Comment: @Jacinto pronto ;)

Comment: Poderia ser *sensíve à caixa*, mas seria preciso explicar, porque o pessoal não iria compreender. Mas eu sugiro, que vocês, o pessoal da computação, adotem e popularizem *caixista*: que discrimina entre caixa alta e caixa baixa.

Comment: @Jacinto justamente o OP sugeriu isto, dentre elas escolhi sugerir algo que teria (supostamente) mais facil compreensão da maior parte das pessoas.

Comment: Poderá encontrar caso-sensitivo, caso sensível a caixa alta,

Comment: @AndréLyra acredita que estes termos sejam compreensíveis aos *"ouvidos"* de todos?

Comment: Não, mas isso é usado na informática, e a pessoa habituada saberá do que se trata.

Comment: @AndréLyra mesmo na informatica o mais comum é o inglês, como eu disse na resposta, traduzir não será algo claro a todos, sendo programação o mais comum acaba por ser o uso do idioma em inglês de algumas palavras.

Comment: Não, se você jogar caso sensitivo no google aparecem muitos resultados em diferentes páginas de informática.